# Set y-axis maximum label to one tick increment higher in NVD3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3 (a wrapper of d3) to draw a line graph. I want the data in the graph to be within the range of the axis. However, it looks inconsistent with the other labels, as the chart displays the max value of my data set on its own. See screenshot:

[image]

In this exanple, 18,554.41 is my highest data point. What I would like to see is the ticks/axis-lables to be in the same order of rounding throughout, with no overflow. i.e. 20,000,18000,16000 etc.

The caveat is that my dataset can vary quite differently - so I can't just set a max. Is there a way of just increasing the tick count by one or something?

Current relevant code:

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                    .showYAxis(true)
                    .forceY([0]);

chart.yAxis
         .axisLabel('£')
         .tickFormat(d3.format(','))
         .ticks(8);
```

EDIT: added https://jsfiddle.net/60equ79h/2/

on the fiddle, I would like the first data set's topmost label to be 10,000. the second would be 80. i.e I would like to the y-axis to be increased by one tick

Comment: Can you create a working example?

Comment: Have you tried .showMinMax(false)

Comment: Yes but removing the max results in the highest axis label being 18000, which is below my highest data point. I'd like it to be 20000

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can force the `yAxis` to have the values you define. You can hard code the values or write something clever to identify the min & max for your `yAxis`.

Update your chart to have the following:

```
chart.forceY([0, 20000]); // [min, max]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This won't work for me. As I mentioned in the question, the max will vary a lot depending on the data set I am using

Comment: @MartinM : You have control of the data you pass in to the chart. So its not going to be hard for you to identify the varying Min & Max values in your data!

Comment: But I do not have control of how the rounding of the labels is done by nvd3. So if I set to the max value of data, the last label will be inconsistent with the rest right? E.g. max data point is 19,345, then my last two axis labels are 18000 & 19345. I would like to see it as 18000 & 20000. In this example the rounding is every 2000, but other data sets could round differently due to it dealing with much smaller or larger numbers in the data

Comment: @MartinM : Can you put your chart + data in a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Its easier to help you out on that.